# How to get XML tags and value at any level of XML tree using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I want to write PHP functions that return some XML tags with their value regardless meaning, depth or levels. Currently I am avoiding loops to bypass n-level complexity.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
 function readTags($string, $tag)
    {
       $xml=  simplexml_load_string($string) or die("Error: Cannot create object");     
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadXML($string);
        $result = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tag);  
        return  0;    
    }

$input = "<level><code>100</code><level2><code>200</code></level2></level>";
$tag = "<code>";
echo readTags($input, $tag);
?>
```

Return output should be: `<code>100</code><code>200</code>`

```
 <?php
     function readTagValues($string, $tag)
        {
           $xml=  simplexml_load_string($string) or die("Error: Cannot create object");     
            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            $dom->loadXML($string);
            $result = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tag);  
            return  0;    
        }

    $input = "<level><level2><code>222</code></level2></level>";
    $tag = "<code>";
    echo readTagValues($input, $tag);
    ?>
```

Return output should be:`222`

Please help me to write these 2 functions in simple way.

Comment: The question is not off-topic here, but would imho be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @syck except it isn't, because the code is not doing what it should do. Which is broken code. Which we treat as off-topic at Code Review.

Comment: Ok. I did not see any indication in the question that the code would be broken, sorry.